# Guarantee a tracking event via GET request bound to a link occurs

Tags: javascript, http, analytics, tracking

I'm tracking certain events on my site using several client-side tracking systems. They all basically work the same way: bind tracking method to some event (e.g. a click) -> HTTP request gets sent to tracking server containing information about the event as parameters. Here's an example:

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="trackEvent();">
```

My goal is to GUARANTEE that the HTTP request has completed BEFORE the `href` is followed. The challenge is that these tracking systems have no callbacks available. Therefore, I believe the solution is to somehow monitor the requests that are taking place, and make sure the page is not redirected until the relevant request is completed.

So my question is:

1. Is there some kind of global variable that contains information about all the requests that are taking place that would help me accomplish what I want?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way this is typically handled is using a setTimeout, here is an example I've used before:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/foo" onclick="return track(this);">Example Foo</a>`

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var track = function(item){
    if(item.href.indexOf(location.host) === -1){
        var hostname = item.href.split('/')[2].split('.').slice(-2).join('.'),
            params = ['_trackEvent', 'Outbound', hostname, item.href],
            _gaq = [];

        _gaq.push(params);

        setTimeout(function(){
            location.href = item.href;
        }, 100);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, I can see how this helps but it doesn't necessarily guarantee that the tracking request is completed as it assumes 100ms will always be enough time. I was hoping for something similar to the `success` callback when using `$.ajax`. I appreciate your answer and will give this a shot.

Comment: FWIW, I worked with Google Analytics' dev team on this, it is their suggested method. You cannot "guarantee" it will work, but in the vast majority of cases, this is effective. Good luck!